# Camunda- Acessing to a specific json element

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I would like to obtain in a response of http-connector, only the “number” element, but I cannot obtain it.
I’m trying to have an inline Javascript with the following statement:
**S(response).prop(“status”).prop(“number”).numberValue();**
but it shows an error: SPIN/JACKSON-JSON-01004 Unable to find ‘status’

What it’s wrong in the statement?

Rest response to parse:

{
“status”: {
“number”: 200,
“type”: “OK”,
“description”: “Status OK”
}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no obvious issue with your expression. I would debug further to see if *response* indeed contanis the Json string you posted. The error shows that response exists, but the content differs.

This working example I just created may help you:
https://github.com/rob2universe/camunda-http-connector-example

If this does not help, you could share more info, e.g. the process model, server log, service you are calling...